# Callback from a Garbage Collected object

Tags: javascript, scope, garbage-collection

Given an object that communicates over the network like this:

```
function MyObj {
    var self = this;
    self.query = function(callback) {
        self.callback = callback;
        networking.on('close', self.process_data);
        // the networking will take some time
    }
    self.finish = function(data) {
        // called with data from networking

        var result = // ... lengthy data processing

        self.callback(result); // finished processing, use callback
    }
}
```

Which is then used like this:

```
function do() {
    var o = new MyObj();
    o.query(some_global_callback);
}
```

It is obvious that function `do` will have finished before before the object `o` will have had time to call the callback.

What happens **if** between the time that `do` finished and `o` will do his callback **a garbage collection cycle occurs**? Will `o` be garbage collected and its callback never executed ?

Comment: No. Garbage collection never changes observable behaviour.

Comment: Can you please explain why not? Where is the "observable behaviour" stored ? i.e. how does the interpreter know that even though `o` no longer exists, it still has to do the code in `finish` and in callback ? Thank you

Comment: The object stored in `o` continues to exist as long as it needs to. It’s not “destroyed” somehow at the end of `do`; a variable containing a pointer to it just went out of scope.

Comment: that's correct. I edited to emphasize where my dilemma comes from: a GC cycle _**right after** the last pointer to `o` went out of scope_ and _**before** `o` finished_

Comment: It’s not “the last pointer”. It’s just *a* pointer. Since you’re still apparently going to use `self` – a pointer to the same object – in `finish`, it’s definitely not eligible for GC. It kind of pains me to use this terminology, though, because JavaScript engines are free to not implement any of this with GC or pointers.

Comment: The simple version: if you add `self.process_data` as an event listener, it’s not going to be somehow swept out from under you by an implementation detail. It *will* be called if the event emitter calls it. If it’s called, neither will `self.callback` have been magically swept out from under it. In pure JavaScript, you don’t have to worry about garbage collection except in the context of resource usage. It will **never** change your program’s behaviour and is an implementation detail.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.query = function...` and `this.finish = function...`? The code shown in `MyObj()` is creating global variables, which radically changes the scope issues being discussed (and `o.query()` in `do()` would crash).

Comment: @nnnnnn correct ! fixed :)

Comment: Thank you, @Ryan. Those 2 comments make an answer for me ;). Post it and I'll accept